# sony vaio sve14135cnb dual boot help?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, system-installation, vaio

I am new to askubuntu forum!

Ok, my problem is to install ubuntu or any linux os along with windows 8 in uefi mode. so, I want to swipe all my 500gb hard disk and wanted to reinstall windows 8, ubuntu in legacy mod.

But my doubt is, if swept my whole hard disk, dose assist button works properly to view bios settings and vaio rescue center?

please help me, I was tired of searching for solution.  Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If by "swipe" you mean erase all data from the hard-drive, then chances are that the rescue center won't be available any more. And if you don't have installation CDs, then you might not be able to reinstall Windows 8. However you should still be able to see the BIOS settings in any case.